# UnauthorizedException token_rejected

Tags: xero-api

I am using the Demo company to develop.
The company expired so I re-activated it 
However when I try to run my unit test to connect to a table I get the following error

```
Xero.Api.Infrastructure.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException: 
oauth_problem=token_rejected&oauth_problem_advice=
The%20organisation%20for%20this%20access%20token%20is%20not%20active
```

I decided to try and regenerate the keys.
When I go to the App page in developer.xero.com and select the option to do this I get a question

```
Regenerate Keys?
Are you sure you want to regenerate your application keys?
This will break any instance of the application using the old key and secret.
```

I answer Yes, then an error appears briefly at the bottom of the screen in red.

```
Error! Please refresh
```

The dialog does not close.

The keys do not re-generate.

I am using Chrome as the browser on Win 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-generating the demo organisation actually creates a whole new organisation; because of this, your app is still linked to an expired demo organisation, so it won't get new keys.

I think you'll need to create a new app to be able to use your new demo organisation.

Comment: Yes, deleting the old app and creating a new one with new key and secret does the trick :-)